# Unable to Run Update Query in SQL Azure *Invalid object name 'DataSync.provision_marker_dss'.*

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I was syncing my Azure SQL Database with On-Premises SQL Database which created a lot of tables in the Online database (As Usual). Anyway, It was working fine.

Now, I had to re-create the Azure SQL Database. So, I deleted the Sync Group & Sync Agent as well.

Everything's working absolutely fine unless I run an **Update Query** on that database.

Whenever I run Update Query on some of the tables, the database shows the following error.

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure finstock06_dss_update_trigger,
> Line 9 Invalid object name 'DataSync.provision_marker_dss'.

There is no such table I ever created on the database.But it's name shows that it was one of the automatically created tables while syncing. (But why here? I have re-created the database)

Although, I created all the tables again on new database but facing this issue.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: go to the trigger in questions and find out what the missing object is. Then search for said object. Youll find that it is indeed missing

Comment: @DougCoats! I didn't understand
Can you please explain a little more?
Where to find this object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had no sync groups left, and deleted all DataSync tables, but still got the error.
Triggers had to be deleted manually too:
https://richardjgreen.net/repairing-damaged-sql-azure-sync-group/

Comment: Thanks a lot man!
I got into the same problem again & your solution worked

Comment: you are a lifesaver! thanks a lot! it worked finally.